# removing duplicates from an arraylist using this code but ignoring case

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, case-insensitive

Ok so nothing has really struck me as a good code set to remove duplicates in an ArrayList without creating a whole new array except this code from CarlJohn. I have tried to respond but my rep points are to low.... still....

So the code is working great minus one exception, it is not ignoring the case so I still get duplicates.

```
ArrayList<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
lst.add("ABC");
lst.add("ABC");
lst.add("ABCD");
lst.add("ABCD");
lst.add("ABCE");

System.out.println("Duplicates List " + lst);

Object[] st = lst.toArray();
for (Object s : st) {
    if (lst.indexOf(s) != lst.lastIndexOf(s)) {
        lst.remove(lst.lastIndexOf(s));
    }
}

System.out.println("Distinct List "+lst);
```

Output is

```
Duplicates List [ABC, ABC, abc, ABCD, ABCD, ABCE, aBCe]
Distinct List [ABC, abc, ABCD, ABCE, aBCe]
```

So how do I modify this to ignore the case of the words it is checking.

Comment: so, the case of the output doesn't matter? In that case, just make everything lower or uppercase before running that code.

Comment: Users can input whatever they want. Its names of items that they enter to create a spinner. So I just want to clean up their input when its displayed but not change the core data.

Comment: well then, if the user inputs "ABC" and "aBc", how do you know which one they want retained?

Comment: The input is proper names and they may cap it sometimes and not others.

Answer (score 2):

use `compareToIgnoreCase` method of the String class

Comment: Of course, this won't work with his use of `lastIndexOf`

Comment: So where would I put that? Might have to toss all this out and figure out another method.

Comment: yeah actually i figured that out after posting the answer but using that might make your code cleaner. As you can see you can directly ask for an iterator from the arraylist rather then making an array of object. Just a suggestion

Comment: @Girish - I'm new to java so not sure what to change. I tried 4 code sets before I settled on this one not thinking of the input of proper names might not be capitalized all the time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

String has method toUpperCase and toLowerCase, you can make both of this strings to lowerCase and then compare them